# Not able to use Boolean as datatype in C# as a replacement to Bit datatype of SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I know the `Bit` datatype of SQL Server is equivalent to `Boolean` datatype of C# from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Since `Bit` can take values 0, 1 or `Null`  from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx

I was initializing my variable in C# to 0.

Example:

```
Boolean exmVar = 0;
```

However I get an error:

> Constant value cannot be converted to a bool.

FYI, I'm converting a stored procedure into C# code, so I have to use `Bit` equivalent only.

Please let me know if any other datatype can be used.

Comment: `Boolean exmVar = false;`

Comment: yea but the point is that the variable should be able to hold only values 0, 1 or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Bit` value can take values **0**, **1** or **null** where as a `Boolean` value can only take values of **true** or **false**.

In order to map your bit to a datatype correctly, you need a `Nullable Boolean` which can take values of **true**, **false** or **null**.

Declare it as such:

```
Boolean? exmVar;
```

And you can assign it like this:

```
exmVar = true;

exmVar = false;

exmVar = null;
```

If you would like to assign 0 or 1 to your boolean variable, you must use `Convert.ToBoolean`

```
exmVar = Convert.ToBoolean(0); // Sets exmVar to false
exmVar = Convert.ToBoolean(1); // Sets exmVar to true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still the `bool` type, but you need to use *nullable types*:

```
bool? value = null; // Same as Nullable<bool> value = null
```

This is a feature that came with C# 2.0 and it allows to box value types (structures) as `Nullable<T>` using `?` as syntactic sugar.

That is, you can declare an `if` statement as follows:

```
if(value != null)
{
}
```

...or also:

```
if(value.HasValue)
{
}
```

...and get is value either using syntactic sugar (i.e. just using the variable *as is*) or accessing its value (i.e. `myVar.Value`).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mathis' answer:

```
//exmVar=false,exmVar=true,exmVar=null
bool?exmVar =item.HasValue?:item.Value:null;
```